# JLabel positioning

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, layout-manager

I've started doing some experiences with Swing in Netbeans.
I've created two panels and inside each one I've inserted one `JLabel`.

How can I define the vertical position of my label inside the frame?

Since I'm unable to align the two labels (one on each panel) I would like to set each one to some vertical alignment.

Comment: BTW - `JLabel`, `JPanel` & `JFrame` all have **2** capital letters.  If by `Jlabel`/`Jpanel`/`Jframe` you mean the J2SE classes, please use correct case.  If not, please mention which 3rd party API is being used.

Comment: Ok. Will be more careful next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Layouts with layout padding and component borders.

See:

- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
setBounds(x,y,width,height);

JLabel label = new JLabel();

label.setBounds(10,10,40,20);
```